# Two problems with Excel graphing

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

See the following figure

[image]

I have two problems with Excel 2013, I am not sure how to solve these:

1) The axis title overlaps the data values on all my axes. From the figure, I am unable to change the margins in excel. How can I move the axis title so it does not overlap the data on the axes?

2) The legend element in Excel 2013 is unable to distinguish between dashed and undashed graphs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re 1: the plot area overlaps with the axis title. Select the plot area and resize it.

Re 2: Select a different dash pattern. The phenomenon you describe only occurs with the longest dash. Go for a dash type with a shorter dash instead.

Comment: And who thinks this deserves a downvote almost two years after the post?